When did Oriental (Monophyzite) churches begin to call themselves “Miaphysites”?
I came across information that this was done very recently by an Ethiopian church figure, engaging in Ecumenism.

can you provide a source please

@depperm I read that from a comment in apologetics group.

The OP begs the question: "when did these churches ever accept the designation 'Monophysite?'" I do not think that the Oriental Christian churches ever accepted the this label.
As I understand the term, miaphysitism is used by these churches to distinguish their teaching from the idea  that Jesus' humanity was completely subsumed in his divinity.  This is the classic monophysite position attributed to Eutyches. Miaphysitism, often associated with Cyril of Alexandria ("One Nature united out of two")  emphasizes that Christ is both divine and human in one unified nature - as opposed to the orthodox teaching that Christ has two natures united in one person. There is a good article on miaphysitism in the Orthodox wiki. Suffice it to say that the Oriental churches were often accused of monophysitism but they rejected this label and insisted they affirmed Jesus' full humanity as well as his full divinity.
Conclusion: The Oriental Orthodox Churches never called themselves "monophysites." They believe themselves to be orthodox Christians who adhere to miaphysitism, while mainstream churches teach diaphysitism. I have no information as to whether they actually call themselves "miaphysites." However, that has long been their theology, as opposed to actual monophysitism.

Monophyzitism should not be identified with Eutychianism. This is just one of the early Monophyzite radical sects. The introduction of the term Miaphysitizm is completely unjustified and confusing. It is easier to call them moderate monophysites.
//Miaphysitism, often associated with Cyril of Alexandria ("One Nature united out of two")// - Cyril of Alexandria professed another formula - “one incarnate nature of the Word”. In fact this is a Dyophysite formula. Because there is one divine nature, not composite. So one incarnate divine nature means 1 + 1.

//Suffice it to say that the Oriental churches were often accused of monophysitism but they rejected this label// - I think they started to reject it only recently. During the Ecumenistic times. Even in some their official documents they applied to themselves the term “Monophyzite”.
//and insisted they affirmed Jesus' full humanity as well as his full divinity.// - at least early Monophyzites including moderate ones were were Gnostic. They thought that human nature was somehow absorbed by the divine. I’m sure today they de facto or even de jure have some similar ideas.
